# Showing that $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^6 + n^2 + 1}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show that $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^6 + n^2 + 1}}$ converges. I tried the ratio test and the root test but both were inconclusive. Next I thought about using the comparison test but I can't figure out a series to compare it to.

Comment: Note that $n^6 + n^2 + 1>n^6$.

Comment: That's right, Thank you. I didn't notice that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sqrt{n^6 + n^2 + 1} > \sqrt{n^6} = n^{3}$.
So $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^6 + n^2 + 1}} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^{3}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}$, which converges.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote that you “can't figure out a series to compare it to”. In cases like this, you ask yourself: how do the numerator and the denominator behave when $n$ is large? Well, the numerator behaves as $n$ and the denominator as $\sqrt{n^6}=n^3$. So, you should compare your series with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{n^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$.